# TYPO3: only have .html at the end of each URL

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, typo3, realurl

I'm using RealURL and the website can be reached by

`www.domain.com/sitemap.html` and `www.domain.com/sitemap`

Now the website should be only reachable by

`www.domain.com/sitemap.html`

How can this be done?

I found the config `'defaultToHTMLsuffixOnPrev' => '.html'`, but I don't know if this is the right option. Also there are some possibilities with `.htaccess`, but this should be only valid for sites (not pictures, pdfs ...). What is the right way doing this?

Answer (score 1):

Use the extension *Force RealURLs*, it forces the access to pages to be made only by the configured URL-scheme in RealURL. [Extension Forcerealurls](http://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/forcerealurls). Tested & certified by me :).

Also, make sure to use canonical URLs in your HEAD section. [German Tutorial](http://www.fladi.de/2009/02/17/howto-einbinden-von-canonical-in-den-header-mit-typo3/). Use [Canonical](http://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/canonical) if you don't like to fiddle around with TypoScript.

There is an extension that promises to solve both issues, but I haven't tested it yet: [Extension Stop Duplicate Content](http://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/cps_stopdc)